# using gedit in Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, gedit

I use gedit for files that I also need in Windows. For the files, I use the Windows-1250 code page. In the Ubuntu, I paste texts and sometimes after that I cannot save the file in the 1250 code page. I wish to continue editing such file opened with the Windows-1250 encoding, but to display it in a way that shows the characters that I need to correct (manually) to be able to save the file in the desired code page. I have seen such displaying for other files, where the "bad" character is displayed as a 4 numbers square table, but I cannot achieve such displaying intentionally. Is it possible? How?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can open a text file with that encoding this way:

```
gedit --encoding=WINDOWS-1250 myFile.txt
```

If you wish gEdit to use this encoding by default you can change the way it starts in the Main Menu application (search for it with the Lens). Then go to:

Applications > Accessories > Text Editor

and click "Properties". In the "Command" text box insert the following:

> gedit --encoding=WINDOWS-1250 %U

and then click "Close" and "Close" again.

Comment: Thanks, but I wish to continue editing the file opened with the Windows-1250 encoding; I have edited the question.

Comment: I am asking a related question http://askubuntu.com/questions/341971/how-to-use-the-main-menu

Comment: You should be able to edit the file following the instructions I provided.