# How to use the Main menu?

Tags: 12.04

According to the answer of [using gedit in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/341569/using-gedit-in-ubuntu) I have installed the Main Menu application and I can change the content of the "Command" text box for gedit. But I do not see how to use the menu to start application listed in it, namely the gedit. I have tried the Help button from the Main Menu, but I only got a message

```
Document Not Found
The URI ‘ghelp:user-guide?menu-editor#menu-editor' does not point
to a valid page.
```

. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It appears I need not start an application from the Main Menu to achieve the application to behave according to the Main Menu "Command" text box content. Only now I have realized that the Main Menu dialog with the "Command" text box has a title 'Launcher Properties'.

After the change in the Main Menu "Command" text box for gedit according to the mentioned answer, it is sufficient to click the gedit icon yet locked in the Launcher or click the name of the *.txt file in Krusader for gedit to open files with my desired coding Windows-1250. It means that its 'Character Encoding: Automatically' is now sufficient for it.